# Payara-Server - Write timeout exceeded when trying to flush the data

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, payara

I'm receiving this exception from Payara Server 4.1.1.164 when requesting different web services (Jersey 2.23.1) in a deployed JavaEE Application.

I don't know the reason of the exception and either exactly When it appears because in some test environments with the same payara server configuration it turns up but in other never has emerged.

Can Someone help me about what could be the problem here? Any help will be grateful.

```
[2017-03-22T17:20:03.200+0100] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1490199603200] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Alexia-BE]: Servlet.service() for servlet Alexia-BE threw exception
java.io.IOException: Write timeout exceeded when trying to flush the data
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:1004)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:715)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:307)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:190)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception happens when it takes too long to write a piece of response, probably due to network problems. It doesn't mean that the problem is that writing the whole response takes too much, but writing a piece of a response happens to be too long in some cases, leading to the exception.

You can try increasing the TCP transport write timeout (In Admin console, go to Network → Transports → TCP and modify Write Timeout). or disable it by setting the value to -1.

Comment: Unfortunately Payara 5 doesn't accept negative values !

Comment: In Payara 5, you can set it to 0 to disable the timeout.

Comment: More precise; Configurations > Server-config > Network Config > Transports > TCP > Write Timeout

Answer (score 1):

We had this happen to us when wrongly using a `@POST` annotation on an endpoint instead of a `@GET`. The endpoint worked fine on most of out developer machines but failed on one dev's machine and, finally, in production. Replacing `@POST` with `@GET` fixed the problem for us.

I can only speculate what caused the problem to occur when using POST.